# different product with muti store

Tags: multistore

i created a second store for my website.
the version magento is 1.7.0.2.

i would like to have for each store,different products.
so, i create a second defaut category for my products of my second store.

at the moment, it work because when i add a product, i choose the good category.
the problem is when i research products on my first store, i find products of my second store.

is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: I remember Visibility to be at store level. You can turn it off for the products in particular store. Then, they should not appear in search results.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude unwanted products from Catalog->Manage products->Product->Websites

Please note! For this to work you need to assign store views to separate websites.